# conditional loop in R dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to get this done in R. The cells in columns 2,3 and 4 contain numbers greater than 10 or 'NA'. Since this is already filtered data, I want to crosscheck with cells in columns 5,6 and 7. The datapoint in columns 5, 6 or 7 contain some alphabetical annotations. If the cells in columns 2,3 or 4 contain 'NA', then I want to convert the corresponding cell values in columns 5, 6 or 7 as 'N' or 'NA'.

My sample data is as follows:

```
ID S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6  
M1 11 20 NA  C  C  C   
M2 NA 123 21 T  T  R  
M3 NA NA 27  A  A  M  
M4 65 23 NA  G  G  C  
M5 12 NA 13  T  G  C
```

My desired output is::

```
ID S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6  
M1 11 20 NA  C  C  N   
M2 NA 123 21 T  N  R  
M3 NA NA 27  N  N  M  
M4 65 23 NA  G  G  N  
M5 12 NA 13  T  N  C
```

Thanks in advance.
Jerry

Comment: Just checking--the second line of your desired output is wrong, correct?

Comment: yes you are correct. i think it should be N T R

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
library(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(list(ID=c("M1","M2"), S1=c(11,NA), s4=c("C", "T")))

#   ID S1 s4
#1: M1 11  C
#2: M2 NA  T

data[, s4 := ifelse(is.na(S1), NA, s4)]

#   ID S1 s4
#1: M1 11  C
#2: M2 NA NA
```

Comment: how to write the same thing for 200 x 200 datatable.

Comment: Search for apply a function on multiple columns in R.